# Get image extension from file got with file_get_contents

Tags: php

How do I get the file extension from $image?

```
$image = file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: It'd be better to get it from `$url`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier to do it using the filename.

Use [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/getimagesize)`($url)`. In particular, see index 2 of the resulting array.

Comment: thanks. I'm using it. Just a question, how do you get the file size? (kb/mb size)

Comment: @Liso22: `filesize($url)`, or `strlen($image)`.

Comment: @Liso22: If your fetching a URL you should use `strlen` so you don't perform a 2nd HTTP request. To make it human readable (kb/mb) you need to write a loop that divides the value by 1024 on each pass while the value is > 1024. If you cant find an example function open a new question and I will answer with a efficient function that performs this.

Comment: thanks. so basically `$image = file_get_contents($url); strlen($image)/1024` would return kilobytes right? maybe I didn't get it right

Answer (score 2):

You can't, you only have the contents. Get it from `$url` instead if possible:

```
$extension = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```